# Is this SQL line valid?

Tags: php, sql, database

Trying to do a page system, and wondering if this code is valid...

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY `date` DESC WHERE id > '". $startat ."' AND id < '". $nextPage ."' LIMIT 25")
```

Comment: Did you get an (SQL) error when trying? If so: it's probably not valid.....

Comment: Was your problem solved? If not update us on the rest of the problem. Or accept an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it not valid. `Order By` must be near the end, cannot be in the middle.

Also you should not be using mysql_query, it is unsafe. Use PDO instead.

```
SELECT * FROM blog_posts 
WHERE id > '". $startat ."' 
AND id < '". $nextPage ."' 
ORDER BY `date` DESC 
LIMIT 25"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have the clauses in the wrong order - try this:

```
$get = mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        blog_posts 
    WHERE 
        id > '". $startat ."' 
        AND id < '". $nextPage ."' 
    ORDER BY 
        `date` DESC 
    LIMIT 25");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like

```
  <br>
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE id > \
'". $startat ."' AND id < '". $nextPage ."' 
ORDER BY date DESC  LIMIT 25");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses are backwards. Try:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM blog_posts 
WHERE id > '". $startat ."' AND id < '". $nextPage ."'
ORDER BY `date` DESC 
LIMIT 25"
```

And I hope `$startat` and `$nextPage` don't come from user input anywhere. You should really be using PDO or mysqli instead - mysql_query is deprecated for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `order by` part should come after the `where clause`.

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        blog_posts 
    WHERE 
        id > '". $startat ."' 
        AND id < '". $nextPage ."' 
    ORDER BY 
        `date` DESC 
    LIMIT 25"
```